# How to lock/unlock cell with index search in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, locking, cell

I want to unlock cell when it matches the criteria using `index-match` formula.

I tried a lot but it didn't work. Could you tell me my mistake(s)?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_ChangeS(ByVal Target As Range)
  If[X9] > "42401" Then
      ActiveSheet.Unprotect("pswrd")[ = INDEX(A16: L35, MATCH(X9, A16: A35, 0), MATCH("GPF", A16: L16, 0))].Locked = False
      ActiveSheet.Protect("pswrd")
  Else
      ActiveSheet.Unprotect("pswrd")[ = INDEX(A16: L35, MATCH(X9, A16: A35, 0), MATCH("GPF", A16: L16, 0))].Locked = True
      ActiveSheet.Protect("pswrd")
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you describe "it didn't work" in a tiny little bit more details? What happened? What didn't happen? Exactly what's *supposed* to happen? Got an error? What was it? Your question as it stands is incomplete, please [edit].

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo here, or your actual sub, but `If[X9]` should have a space, `If [X9] > ...`.

Comment: You need to change Worksheet_ChangeS to Worksheet_Change (i.e. without the S on the end).  Also, the code within square brackets needs to be on separate lines.

Comment: Sir, targeted cell does not unlock when meets the criteria, however password is correct.